# nodejs redirect user with data

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, redirect

The client will log in by sending a POST request to my server. My server will check this. If it works, I want to send the welcome page to the client but insert some data into it via a templating engine. I have everything but the redirect part figured out. This is what I have (I am using handlebars as a templating engine):

```
app.post("/loginAttempt",function(req, res)
{
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
        //if credentials are incorrect, data is false
        //otherwise, data is a html file as a string
        var data = await checkCredentials(username,password);
        if(data === false)
        {
            res.send("fail");
        }
        else
        {
            //not a real function, just using this to simplify code for this post
            var temp = compileWithHandlebars("./front-end/welcome.html",{myData: data});
            res.send(temp);
        }
});
```

The problem with this is it sends a html file as a string instead of redirecting. This means the user sees no change in url, so they cannot hit the back button to go back to the login page.

Comment: Have you tried it with `res.render`?

Comment: Can you share the code of `compileWithHandlebars` method?

Comment: var temp = handlebars.compile(source)(templateData); ---------source is the html file read as a string

Comment: it is hard to post because it is actually an asynchronous call so my real code has res.send inside a callback function

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the temp is a string!

```
   app.post("/loginAttempt",function(req, res)
    {
        var username = req.body.username;
        var password = req.body.password;
            //if credentials are incorrect, data is false
            //otherwise, data is a html file as a string
            var data = await checkCredentials(username,password);
            if(data === false)
            {

                res.status(404).send("fail"); //<==
            }
            else
            {
                //not a real function, just using this to simplify code for this post
                //var temp = compileWithHandlebars("./front-end/welcome.html",{myData: data});


                res.redirect("./front-end/welcome.html",{data:myData});
            }
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The client still recives a html file as a string instead of being redirected